# how to remove specific characters in vi or vim editor

Tags: vim

I have some txt in vi:

```
|NC_004718|29751nt|SARS
|NC_045512|29903nt|Severe
|NC_004718|29751nt|SARS
|NC_045512|29903nt|Severe
|NC_004718|29751nt|SARS
```

now I want to replace remove everything after NC_004718, my expected output is:

```
NC_004718
NC_045512
NC_004718
NC_045512
NC_004718
```

How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a substitution with regular expression to match the entire string and to capture what you would like to keep in parentheses. That way you can then replace the entire string with just the match.

```
:%s/^|\([^|]\+\)|.\+/\1/
```

To break down what is happening:

1. `%` means that you want to apply the command to each line within the file.
2. `s` means that you are doing substitution command (on each line). The `s` command has a syntax of `s/<regular expression pattern>/<replacement>/<flags>`
3. The regular eression pattern in the above command is `^|\([^|]\+\)|.\+`.

   - `^` means match from the line start.
   - `|` matches the character `|`.
   - `\([^|]\+\)` matches all characters except for the character `|`. Note that the real regular expression is actually `([^|]+)`, the additional `\` characters are there because Vim needs to know that they are intended to be special characters for processing and not exact characters it needs to match. Also note that the parentheses are there to capture the match into a group (see below).
   - `|` again matches the actual character `|`.
   - `.\+` matches all characters until the end of the line. Note that the `.` is considered special character by default but `+` still needs a preceding `\`.
4. The replacement text is only `\1`. This denotes that Vim should replace the text with whatever was captured in the first group (i.e. the first set of parentheses).
5. There are no flags with this command so there is nothing after the last `/`.

Answer (score 4):

For example,

```
:g/NC_\d\+/normal! ygnV]p
```

- `:g/regex/` to match lines
- `normal!` to execute Normal mode commands
- `ygn` to yank the text previously matched by `:g`
- `V` to select the whole line
- `]p` or `p` to replace the line with the match

Comment: I tested this with the example text -- and it deleted all the text.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only lines like those you have shown try:

```
 :%norm xf|D
```